# Tags created via Asana API not associated with tasks are not returned in tags API call

Tags: asana

In my tests... the newly created tag is not in the get request for tags when it isn't associated with a task. Once associated with a task it seems to appear in the response. However, once removed from a task it disappears from response.

Answer (score 0):

For all intents and purposes, a tag that's no longer associated with any tasks doesn't exist. You may still see autocomplete suggestions due to caching in the web client, but the API won't show them anymore.

The long-term goal is to have tags simply behave like text labels. A string would uniquely identify a tag, and we can stop messing around with IDs and pretending they're proper resources.